# How to create categories and sub-categories in left side in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I am beginner in `open-cart`.I currently working in **web2print**  extension in open-cart.I need to create categories and sub categories in left side.I already display categories menu in left side via admin panel,but i need to create display categories and sub-categories in left side bar with similar manner.

```
 <div class="box clsLeft_menu">
  <div class="box-heading">Some of our specialties:</div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <ul class="box-category">
      <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
      <li>
        <?php if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="active"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php foreach ($category['children'] as $child) { ?>
          <li>
            <?php if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>" class="active"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"> - <?php echo $child['name']; ?></a>
            <?php } ?>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display categories and sub-categories in opencart.
example:

--main categories

```
--sub 1
--sub 2
--sub 3
```

--main categories

```
--sub 1
--sub 2
```

how to solve it ?Please guide me...

Comment: I am waiting for responsive answer...any one please guide me.....

Answer (score 1):

Search for vertical accordion menu. There are plenty of plugins available, though not directly for opencart, can be easily added.

Couple of example:

http://visionwidget.com/jquery-accordion-slider-menu.html

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-tutorial-create-a-jquery-menu-slider/

Comment: Hi @Dhaval Desai....thank u for responsive answer....i`ll check it out...thank u so much.....and its applicable for open cart ah?

Comment: Yes it is. You have to add class name in list tag (ul and li) and add corresponding javascript/jquery and css.

Comment: its working perfectly......@Dhaval Desai......thank u....so much....for responsive answer...